# if f(n) = 2n^2 and g(n) = 1.01^n. Is f(n) = O(g(n))? Is f(n) = Ω(g(n))?

Tags: logic, runtime, time-complexity, discrete-mathematics

Let f(n) = 2n^2 and g(n) = 1.01^n. Is f(n) = O(g(n))? Is f(n) = Ω(g(n))? Justify your answers with a proof.

Answer (score 1):

Think about what the graphs of those functions look like for very large n. Which one grows faster (i.e. overtakes the other in the long run)? Time complexities denote the asymptotic running-time of an algorithm.